# percentage sign does not appear

Tags: jquery

I want to display textbox with a % sign next to the textbox but the % does not appear, how do I make it appear?

Below is my code:

```
     var $weightText = $("<input type='text' id='txtWeightRow' maxlength='5' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'/>").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                 .attr('value',$this.val())
```

Comment: That's not how you add an element in jQuery. What your code is doing is looking for a textbox (with an incorrect selector) and adding a name attribute to it.

Comment: I do want to select details from another textbox into this textbox

Comment: @jb11: `$(some_pile_of_html)` is just fine, you'd want to `.append` it (or similar) to get it into the DOM but that's a separate matter.

Comment: Never knew that. I'm not sure why you wouldn't use the ID selector though

Comment: I do have an append, it is just not in this code :) in my question

Comment: If you're basically duplicating an element why not use .clone()?

Comment: @jb11: The OP isn't using an ID selector because they want to *create* some DOM nodes, not *select* them. Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/u3ZUF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> If a string is passed as the parameter to `$()`, jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it has `<tag ... >` somewhere within the string). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as explained above. But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these elements.

Looks like jQuery is trying to figure out what is in that string and not quite getting it right. If you [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/VNda6/) (at least in a WebKit browser):

```
console.log($("<input type='text' id='txtWeightRow'>%"));
console.log($("<input type='text' id='txtWeightRow'>%<br>"));
```

You'll see that only the `<input>` comes out in the first one but you'll get all three for the second. I'd call that a bug in jQuery.

I think you'll have to do it in two steps to make it work:

```
var $weightText = $("<input type='text' id='txtWeightRow'/>").attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
//...
$(whatever).append($weightText).append('%');
```

where `whatever` does, of course, depend on where you're trying to put the `<input>`.

Answer (score 2):

To add a % next to your text box, you'd want to do something like this:

```
$('#txtWeightRow').after('%');
```

Comment: i added an extra bit of code I did not put in previously in my question

Comment: it comes back with an error stating unrecognize expression '%'

Answer (score 1):

```
 var $weightText = $("<input type='text' id='txtWeightRow'/>").attr('name',$this.attr('name'));
 $("#txtWeightRow").after('%');
```

Comment: it comes back with an error stating unrecognize expression '%'

Comment: i added an extra bit of code I did not put in previously in my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the value of another textbox you should do something like this:

```
var txtValue = $('#wanted-textbox').val();
```

Comment: its ok i have got it working the way I have done it, thanks tho :)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the situation. `var $x = $("<input type='text' id='txtWeightRow'/>")` creates a new node for an `<input>`, `$('body').append($x)` would put that node on the page and the `<input>` would appear.

Comment: Now I see it. Initially there was no mention that the generated node would be added so it seemed completely wrong